# Facebook api not working in my emulator?

Tags: android, facebook

I have implemented login with facebook in my project.
The code is below:

```
public class login extends Activity{
ImageView fbtn;
private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
static Facebook facebook = new Facebook("271089732997803");
String access_token;
long expires;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yf_login1);
    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
    fbtn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.fbtn);
    fbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(access_token != null) {
                facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
                Log.v("access_token", access_token);
            }
            if(expires != 0) {
                facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
                Log.i("expires", ""+expires);
            }
            if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {

                facebook.authorize(login.this,new String[] {}, new DialogListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                        editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                        editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
                        editor.commit();

                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {

                    }
            });
            }
            else{
                 startActivity(new Intent(login.this,ChooseTeam.class));
            }

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {    
    super.onResume();
    facebook.extendAccessTokenIfNeeded(this, null);
}
```

Now my question is when i click on the the fb button it will load the progress bar and after 30-40 second it returns the same page.

The most important thing is when i run the same project in my another pc it will run perfectly, opens the dialog of login for the facebook and got the value in my preferences. But in my case i cannot even get the preferences made in my data.

What will be the problem in my emulator?? I am using eclipse galilio and sdk20.

Comment: Have u installed facebook app in your emulator or not first tell me and show ur facebook connector class code too

Comment: I have used facebook sdk in the code and i don't have any more connector class of facebook. I wanna implement login with facebook only SSO in my application.My other pc does not have facebook app installed in emulator But it works.what to do now?

Comment: have u updated ur appkey using hash key or not for SSO

Comment: yes it is generated with openssl otherwise in other systems this code wont work. This login dialog doesn't open in my emulator only. In other systems it works. What should i change in my system.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11936/android-lite come here for discussion bcz we sholud have to avoid comment again again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution actually my antivirus is blocked the internet for the emulator. So i have uninstalled the antivirus and run the app and it works.

Thank you all for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....
and use this Permission for Share in Facebook..

private String[] mPermissions={"publish_stream"};

```
mFb.authorize(SettingActivity.this, mPermissions,new com.fbintegration.Facebook.DialogListener()
                        {

                            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e)
                            {

                            }

                                public void onError(DialogError e) 
                                {

                                }

                                public void onComplete(Bundle values) 
                                {


                                    SessionStore.save(mFb, getApplicationContext());



                                }

                            public void onCancel() 
                            {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }
                        });
```

and this is Facebook Connector Class....

```
public class FacebookConnector
{

    private Facebook facebook = null;
    private Context context;
    private String[] permissions;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private Activity activity;
    //private SessionListener mSessionListener = new SessionListener();;

    public FacebookConnector(String appId,Activity activity,Context context,String[] permissions) 
    {
        this.facebook = new Facebook(appId);

        SessionStore.restore(facebook, context);


        this.context=context;
        this.permissions=permissions;
        this.mHandler = new Handler();
        this.activity=activity;
    }

    public void login() 
    {
        if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) 
        {
            facebook.authorize(this.activity, this.permissions,new LoginDialogListener());
        }
    }

    /*public void logout() 
    {
        SessionEvents.onLogoutBegin();
        AsyncFacebookRunner asyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(this.facebook);
        asyncRunner.logout(this.context, new LogoutRequestListener());
    }*/

    public void postMessageOnWall(String msg)
    {
        if (facebook.isSessionValid())
        {
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("message", msg);
            try
            {
                //JSONObject response=Util.parseJson(facebook.request("me/feed", parameters,"POST"));
                String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters,"POST");
                System.out.println(response);
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }   

    private final class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener
    {
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) 
        {
            SessionEvents.onLoginSuccess();
        }

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error)
        {
            SessionEvents.onLoginError(error.getMessage());
        }

        public void onError(DialogError error)
        {
            SessionEvents.onLoginError(error.getMessage());
        }

        public void onCancel() 
        {
            SessionEvents.onLoginError("Action Canceled");
        }
    }


    private class SessionListener implements AuthListener, LogoutListener
    {

        public void onAuthSucceed()
        {
            SessionStore.save(facebook, context);
        }

        public void onAuthFail(String error) {
        }

        public void onLogoutBegin() {           
        }

        public void onLogoutFinish() {
            SessionStore.clear(context);
        }
    }

    public Facebook getFacebook() 
    {
        return this.facebook;
    }
}
```

Comment: i din't have to change my code i want to run my on my emulator as it is working in another system fine.